# Prove Product Property of Eigen Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that A and B are both nxn matrices, that u is an eigen vector for both A corresponding to λ1 and B corresponding to λ2. Prove that u is also an eigen vector for the product AB

Comment: So what have you done? Have you tried to evaluate $ABu$?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to set it up at all. I know that det(A-λI)=λ1 and the same goes for B but I'm just not sure how to go from there.

Comment: How would I write AB in matrix form?

Comment: If $C$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $C$ if there exists a constant $\lambda$ such that $$Cv = \lambda v$$

Hence what you want to do is to show that there is some constant $\lambda$ such that

$$(AB)u = \lambda u$$

Start therefore by trying to evaluate $ABu$.

Comment: You are told that $Au = \lambda_1 u$. What is $Bu$ equal to? And hence what is $ABu$?

Comment: So then Bu=λ2u so would that mean A=λ1u*u^-1 and therefore A=λ1? Or does that not make sense since A is a matrix and λ1 is a scalar?

Comment: That makes no sense because $u^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

$$ABu = A(Bu) = A(\lambda_2 u) = \  ...$$

Comment: Just compute $ABu$ for Justin's sake.

Comment: copper.hat not asking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(AB)u=A(Bu)=A(\lambda_2u)=\lambda_2Au=\lambda_2\lambda_1u$

So $u$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1\lambda_2$.

Comment: Okay I see what you're getting at I did A(λ2u) with a problem from my book and I think I got the same thing. Thanks